# What happens to $E_n$ of quantum harmonic oscillator if the potential changes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, harmonic-oscillator

As we all know there is the normal quantum harmonic oscillator with potential $V= \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}$ and we get $E_n =\hbar\omega(n+1/2)$

What is my $E_n$ when the potential $V= 2m\omega^2x^2$ or how can I calculate it?

Comment: You can redefine $\omega$ to $\omega'$ such that the new potential has the same form as the original one. So the energy level should take the same form(except $\omega$ changes to $\omega'$ ).

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Frank
$$V'=2m\omega'^2x^2=\frac{1}{2}m(2\omega')^2x^2=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$
Thus
$$E'_n=\hbar\omega'\left(n'+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\hbar\omega \left(n'+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2E_n$$

Answer (score 0):

The hamiltonian $H = {p^2}/{2m} + m\omega^2x^2/2$ has the spectrum $E_n=\hbar\omega(n+1/2)$. Replacing $\omega \to 2\omega$ you get the hamiltonian $H = {p^2}/{2m} + 2m\omega^2x^2$, which then must have the same spectrum with $\omega \to 2\omega$, so $E_n \to E_n = 2\hbar\omega(n+1/2)$